# Karma returns error and executes 0 out of 0, even though I have one test using Jasime

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

This is my `karma/karma.conf.js`:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Mon Jan 04 2016 16:17:18 GMT-0500 (EST)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: true,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

and this is my `karma/tests/test_post.js`:

```
describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function() {
    beforeEach(module('PostPageApp'));

    var ctrl;

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
        ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl');
    }));

    it('Show have an add and logout function', function() {
        expect(ctrl.add).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

and this is `../post.js`:

```
angular.module("PostPageApp", ["BaseApp"])
    .controller("MainCtrl", ["$http", "$window", "BaseService", function($http, $window, BaseService) {

        var self = this;

        self.add = function() {
            BaseService.add.post(self.post, function() {
                self.cerrorMessages = BaseService.cerrorMessages;
            });
        };

        self.logoutUser = function() {
            BaseService.logout();
        };

    }]);
```

Now, when I do `karma start`, it returns this:

```
04 01 2016 16:48:10.137:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.17 server started at http://localhost:9876/
04 01 2016 16:48:10.144:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
04 01 2016 16:48:13.138:INFO [Chromium 47.0.2526 (Ubuntu 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket ayhU7qR23sshUzi3AAAA with id 50222765
Chromium 47.0.2526 (Ubuntu 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.013 secs / 0 secs)
```

Any idea why it is executing 0 out of 0 and returning an error? I thought it would run

```
it('Show have an add and logout function', function() {
    expect(ctrl.add).toBeDefined();
});
```

Please note that I am new to using Karma and Jasmine so I am still trying to get the hang of all of this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not running any tests because you aren't telling it to load any files into the browser.  I think a lot of people use RequireJS for this, but unfortunately I am not familiar with it.

In `karma.conf.js` under the `files:` section:

1. List your JS dependencies (like JQuery or Angular).
2. List the files that you are testing next.
3. List the test specs themselves last.

For instance:

```
files: [
   'angular.js',
   'app.js',
   'app.spec.js'
]
```

If you don't want certain files to be included then put them in the `exclude` section.  Make sure the file paths are relative to where `karma.conf.js` is located.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest specifying a default path and a pattern at ./karma.conf.js:

```
// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: 'test/',

// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  {pattern: '**/*.js*', included: true}
],
```

It worked for me.